# CakePHP: validation of form upload field if file exists not working

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

CakePHP 2.x: I am struggling with validating an image upload field in a form for adding users. The upload field is not manditory. But it validates the field always as false while the image is uploaded. It seems the whole validation is working partially. Any help would be appreciated

User.php model :

```
public $validate = array(
    'picture' => array(
        'required' => false,
        'allowEmpty' => true,
        'custom' => array(
            'rule' => array('imageExist'),
            'message' => 'There is already a picture with that name on the server'
        )
    ));


// function to check if file already exists
public function imageExist($check) {
    $picturename = $check['picture'];
    $path = WWW_ROOT . 'userimages/';
    $file = $path . $picturename;

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

add.ctp:

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->create('User', array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'role' => 'form', 'div' => false, 'type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->input('username', array('label' => "Username"));
echo $this->Form->input('picture', array('label' => "Avatar", 'type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form>formDefaultActions();
echo $this->Form->end(); 
?>
```

UserController.php:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->User->create();
        // set picture and path
        $filedir = WWW_ROOT . 'userimages/';
        $file = $filedir . $this->request->data['User']['picture']['name'];

        // upload avatar picture
        move_uploaded_file(
            $this->request->data['User']['picture']['tmp_name'],
            $file
        );
        $this->request->data['User']['picture'] = $this->request->data['User']['picture']['name'];
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been added'), 'success' );
            $this->redirect(array(
                'action' => 'index'
            ));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be created. Please, try again'), 'error' );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now what is problem?wat is not working? ur code is awesome .

Comment: It always returns false and even with the false the data is not written to the database, but the image is uploaded

Comment: u check if image already exists on FOLDER on server .OK ?? it should not repeat ok ??

Comment: Provide USer Controller Code u wrote to save image in Databse + image upload

Comment: Hi Angry Bird... Just updated the initial question and added the controller

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your validation before uploading or will be always false. If you upload your file, when cakephp validates your file already exists in folder.

You can just move your logic to something like:

```
$this->request->data['User']['picture'] = $this->request->data['User']['picture']['name'];
if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
    move_uploaded_file(
        $this->request->data['User']['picture']['tmp_name'],
        $file
    );
}
```

Or check, before saving:

```
if ($this->User->validates()) {
    if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
        move_uploaded_file(
            $this->request->data['User']['picture']['tmp_name'],
            $file
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: correct, Bcoz if Validation is successful ,->Then only save image name in DB , And then upload file . +1 :)

Answer (score -1):

comment this

```
  $this->request->data['User']['picture'] = $this->request->data['User']['picture']['name'];
```

and also take off the 2 statements into model, required and allowEmpty.also replace in your controller:

```
if ($this->User->save($this->request->data))
```

with

```
if ($this->User->save($this->request->data['User']))
```

and the pic name should be saved into the db

Comment: OP's code is correct,`$this->User->save($this->request->data))` is perfectly valid,i used it in every project

Comment: yea its a habit i got,both solutions are valid